GTM tags firing in preview mode but events not getting reflected in Google Analytics
I am getting "No google tag found in this container" when I enter measurement id in order to create a new GA4 tag. Is it causing the issue of my tags firing in preview mode but not showing in Google analytics?
I tried creating a Universal Analytics tag instead of GA4 tag but I need tracking id for it which I am not able to find anywhere.
I want that all the firing tags should have their event data reflected in Google Analytics.
